# How to redirect from download (server path) to login form , after server connection failure(using fetch in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, server, fetch, openvpn

> So i'm using fetch and OpenVPN to login to server and download a
> file from a specific path via url. I must send the user to download path, if the download doesn't start then i need to redirect him to login page and then again to download, the problem is that my script
> doesn't work, i get errors like : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'catch' of undefined, Access to fetch at url from origin
> 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled, Failed to
> load resource: net::ERR_FAILED, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
> Failed to fetch. I changed the url option and removed the : mode:
> 'no-cors', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',   'Accept':
> 'application/json',   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } with the
> one i have now at const options. But it still doesn't work after that.
> Any ideas??

```
function SynologyLogin(form) {
    var username = form.username.value;
    var password = form.password.value;
    
    const url =
    'host' +
    username +
    '&passwd=' +
    password +
    '&session=FileStation&format=cookie';
    
    const options = {
    
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    Synologydownload()
    .catch(resp => {
    console.error(resp);
    });
    }
    
    function Synologydownload(){
    fetch('host+path')
    .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
    
      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
          //window.location.href='host+ download_path'
          console.log(data);
      });
    }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
    }
```

Comment: Please reformat your question so it's more readable. 
But a CORS error means that the browser blocks requests to servers which do not allow Cross Origin Requests. You have to enable CORS on your Synology if that's possible. Or you may need to call it from a server instead of the browser.

Comment: I tried with google plugin but it still shows errors, maybe you know how to do the same from the script?